# Multi class in Notepad++

Tags: java

So I am unfamiliar with Notepad++ and have a working program in Blue J.
I tried to transfer it over but I continue to receive the error:

> "Average.java:5: error: class UserInput is public, should be declared in a file named UserInput.java  public class UserInput         ^
>
> Note: Average.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error"

I think it has to do with how I wrote each class in but I am unsure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your editor

Comment: Please don't post your  code as an image next time. Copy-paste it.

Answer (score 2):

Only one public class is allowed in a file, and it should have the same name as the file.

The first solution is quite well define in the error. "*UserInput [...] should be declared in a file named UserInput.java*".
The second solution is to change the visibility of the class

in *A.java*

```
public class A {}
class B{}
protected class C{}
private class D{}

public class E{} //THIS IS NOT ALLOWED, it should be in E.java
```

Note that even if only one public class can be define in a file, it is not mandatory to have a public class.

X.java

```
protected class X{} //this is valid.
```

But don't add another class in this file as public, only `X` can be public in `X.java`

Answer (score 1):

In Java there can only be 1 public class declared per java file. So to quickly resolve your issue you could simply split out the `UserInput` class into it's own file called `UserInput.java`, it is as simple as that.

For a bit complexity though you could look into `Inner Classes` or `Local Classes` which would allow you declare an additional class(es) within the one file.

Have a read of

- [Inner Classes Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)
- [Local Inner Classes Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)

Here is an example of a `LocalClass` (Code taken from [Local Inner Classes Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html))

```
public class LocalClassExample {

    static String regularExpression = "[^0-9]";

    public static void validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2) {
        final int numberLength = 10;

        // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

        // int numberLength = 10;

        class PhoneNumber {

            String formattedPhoneNumber = null;

            PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
                // numberLength = 7;
                String currentNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
                regularExpression, "");
                if (currentNumber.length() == numberLength)
                    formattedPhoneNumber = currentNumber;
                else
                    formattedPhoneNumber = null;
            }

            public String getNumber() {
                return formattedPhoneNumber;
            }

            // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

            // public void printOriginalNumbers() {
                // System.out.println("Original numbers are " + phoneNumber1 +
               // " and " + phoneNumber2);
            // }
        }

    PhoneNumber myNumber1 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber1);
    PhoneNumber myNumber2 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber2);

    // Valid in JDK 8 and later:

    // myNumber1.printOriginalNumbers();

    if (myNumber1.getNumber() == null) 
        System.out.println("First number is invalid");
    else
        System.out.println("First number is " + myNumber1.getNumber());
    if (myNumber2.getNumber() == null)
        System.out.println("Second number is invalid");
    else
        System.out.println("Second number is " + myNumber2.getNumber());

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
       validatePhoneNumber("123-456-7890", "456-7890");
    }
}
```

This code would print out

```
First number is 1234567890
Second number is invalid
```

As @AxelH has stated this could be a bit complex for someone without much knowledge, however this is a fun little exercise to play with. For a more simple I would refer you to @AxelH answer.

Comment: No need to go into inner class here. You can have two classes in a same file, that are on the same "level". (I feel this would be too complicated for newbie...)

Comment: Yeah true and I was going to put that however based on what you have already done which doesn't need saying again I thought I'd add a bit of complexity to it. Albeit I should probably say it really isn't needed, just a fun little exercise though. Yes agree possibly a bit to complex for a newbie

Comment: This mostly need to mention that **each local inner classes defined kill a puppy somewhere in the world!** ;) But this is indeed a pretty fun exercise to do the first time you discover this.

Comment: I like to think of this more like **cracking an egg with a sledgehammer**, probably a bit over kill.

Answer (score 0):

class UserInput is public, should be declared in a file named UserInput.java

I guess the exception is self-explanatory. Just rename to File name to UserInput.java and it will work!

Comment: It's not enough. There can be only one public class per `.java` file